# Checking my question: the function is continuously differentiable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

I solved a question related to first order partial derivatives. Please check my solution. Is it correct and ehough to get sufficient grade from an exam?

I am not sure espacially part-b. Please check better part-b. Thank you:)

[image]

Comment: Part b) isn't sufficient. You checked one sequence converging to $0$, but you'd need to check all. Suggestion: prove an estimate $\left\lvert\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,y)\right\rvert \leqslant (\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^\alpha$ ($z$ is once $x$ and once $y$, $\alpha$ to be determined).

Comment: I could not do what you say. I dont have an enough ability to do this. Please can you show me the solution of part-b below answer part? Please. I need to learn. @DanielFischer

Comment: Write $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Note that $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant r$ and $\lvert y\rvert \leqslant r$. Thus (picking the simpler $\partial f/\partial x$), $\left\lvert\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{2r\cdot r^6}{r^4} = 2r^3$. (At which point I notice that I forgot to include the constant factor in the first comment.) Now, from such an estimate, you should be able to deduce that $\partial f/\partial x$ is continuous in $0$.

Comment: Hmm that's $2r^3$ $\to 0$ as $r \to 0$ And I Will apply similar things to $\partial f / \partial x$ since I found the limit of $f_x$ and $f_y$ is zero, so f is cont at zero. So f is continuously diff. Is that I understand right? @DanielFischer

Comment: To show that $g$ (Note: you wrote $f$ in your solution, better make that $g$) is continuously differentiable, it is sufficient to show that $g$ is everywhere partially differentiable and the partial derivatives are continuous. I suppose you have a theorem stating that, or maybe that is the definition of being continuously differentiable in your lectures. In part a), you have shown that the partial derivatives exist everywhere (by the way, you have a sign error in $\partial g/\partial y$, $4 - 2 = 2$, and not $-2$). In part b), you have to show that they are continuous everywhere. (cont...)

Comment: ... For $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, you can cite a theorem (the partial derivatives are rational functions, hence continuous where the denominator doesn't vanish). To show continuity in $(0,0)$, you can use the estimate above and a similar one for $\partial g/\partial y$.

Comment: Got it perfect:) thank you for help:) I want to tick your such a good answer/ explanation but I am gratifing you just with upvote:) thank you @DanielFischer I Will solve more properly though your explanation.